# Erlang: binary_to_term explanation

Tags: erlang, bytea

I've some old elrang (17.1) project on my hand and I need some help understanding some parts of the code.

Using it I'm creating a object in sets table with those values

{:name=>"TestCurrencies", :value=>["usd", " eur", " pln"] (and uuids of course)

(value is stored as a bytea in Postgres DB)

```
insert_and_return_record(Resource) ->
    #?model_name{account_uuid=AccountUuid, name=Name, value=Value} = Resource,
    Uuid = digits:uuid(AccountUuid),
    LowerValue = to_lower(Value),
    Statement = "INSERT INTO sets(uuid, account_uuid, name, value) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4)",
    {ok, 1} = bep_db:execute(Statement, [Uuid, AccountUuid, Name, term_to_binary(LowerValue)]),
    get_record(AccountUuid, Uuid).
```

This code generates this entry in the db

`cdbee9cb-fc84-53a9-8e8b-22c90a76b211 | a9dbb489-4a97-5b15-bfcf-ca558e01687c | TestCurrencies | \x836c000000036d000000037573646d00000004206575726d0000000420706c6e6a`

And while

```
get_record(AccountUuid, Uuid) ->
    Statement = "SELECT uuid, account_uuid, name, value FROM sets WHERE account_uuid=$1 AND uuid=$2",
    {ok, _Columns, Rows} = bep_db:execute(Statement, [AccountUuid, Uuid]),
    case Rows of
        [] ->
            {error, no_exists};
        [{Uuid, AccountUuid, Name, Value}] ->
            #?model_name{uuid=Uuid, account_uuid=AccountUuid, name=Name, value=binary_to_term(Value)}
    end.
```

Does return proper values, but manually running

`binary_to_term("\x836c000000036d000000037573646d00000004206575726d0000000420706c6e6a").`
returns bad_argument error.

Getting it directly from db with

`SELECT encode(value, 'escape') FROM sets WHERE uuid = 'cdbee9cb-fc84-53a9-8e8b-22c90a76b211';`
`returns`

`\203l\000\000\000\x03m\000\000\000\x03usdm\000\000\000\x04 eurm\000\000\000\x04 plnj`

Could anybody explain to me why is it like that?
Is there a way to get the proper value only using SQL?
Other project written in Ruby needs to communicate with the same db and get the proper values, could it be possible?

I've tried searching the issue, tried manually running it in erlang console. I've tried using SQL.

Comment: *returns bad_argument error.* -- If you don't know  why that is, you need to buy the book "Programming Erlang", read the chapters and do  all the exercises at the end of the chapters until you understand why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 3):

The notation in the text

```
\x836c000000036d000000037573646d00000004206575726d0000000420706c6e6a
```

is `\x` followed by hex encoded binary data. To decode this manually, you can do remove the `\x` and pass it to `binary:decode_hex` as a binary:

```
1> binary_to_term(binary:decode_hex(<<"836c000000036d000000037573646d00000004206575726d0000000420706c6e6a">>)).
[<<"usd">>,<<" eur">>,<<" pln">>]
```

To get the same value with raw SQL, you can do `encode(value, 'hex')`:

```
SELECT encode(value, 'hex') FROM sets WHERE uuid = 'cdbee9cb-fc84-53a9-8e8b-22c90a76b211';
```

---

> Other project written in Ruby needs to communicate with the same db and get the proper values, could it be possible?

You would need to either find a library or write a parser that can parse the Erlang External Term Format (https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html) for this.